# undefined response getting in javascript function ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I am trying to get status of any address,in which request_withd function is call ,then action goes on another function named 'is_address_exist' which is return response status of any address in 
'yes' or 'no' but i am getting 'undefined' response message in console.

```
function is_address_exist(address) {
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var url = '../ withdrawn/address_check/' + address;
  xmlhttp.open('GET', url, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4) {
      if (xmlhttp.status === 200) {
        return xmlhttp.responseText;
      }
    }
  }
}

function request_withd(e) {
  var response_status = is_address_exist(address);
  console.log(response_status);
}
```

Comment: Your first function doesn't always return

Comment: @bugs is this wrong code structure

Comment: @coin-o-pediac  you need to perform your actions within the onreadystatechange function because that piece of code runs async as it is a callback function.

Comment: @AdeoluwaSimeon could u please help me out how can i solve this problem.

Comment: First thing aren't you supposed to pass e like this `function request_withd(e) {
  var response_status = is_address_exist(e);
  console.log(response_status);
}`. If address is not a global variable then this might throw an error

Comment: @VigneshMurugan i am passing address by input field like - var address=document.getElementById("b_address").value;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`is_address_exist()` doesn't return anything here.
Your `return` is happening within a `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = () => ...`

You could either use [`callbacks`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function) or [`promises`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) here.

Callback example:

```
function is_address_exist(address, handler){
    //...
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
       //...
       handler(xmlhttp.responseText);
    });
}

is_address_exist('...', function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

Promise example:

```
function is_address_exist(){
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        //...
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
           //...
           resolve(xmlhttp.responseText);
        });
        xmlhttp.onerror = reject;
    });
}

is_address_exist()
    .then(function (data) {
        console.log(data)
    })
    .catch(console.error.bind(console));
```

Answer (score 1):

The onreadystatechange function is a call back function, it runs async, it should have the intended actions included in its definition. This should work.

```
function is_address_exist(address){
        var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url='../withdrawn/address_check/'+address;
        xmlhttp.open('GET',url,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
         xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
            if(xmlhttp.readyState===4)
            {
             if(xmlhttp.status===200){
                  console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);
                }
              }
            }   
          }
   function request_withd(e){
   is_address_exist(address);
 }
```

Or for non async function

```
function is_address_exist(address) {
  var responseText ="";
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var url = '../ withdrawn/address_check/' + address;
  xmlhttp.open('GET', url, false);
  xmlhttp.send();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4) {
      if (xmlhttp.status === 200) {
        responseText = xmlhttp.responseText;
      }
    }
  }
  return responseText;
}

function request_withd(e) {
  var response_status = is_address_exist(address);
  console.log(response_status);
}
```

Comment: i am getting result in this condition on console . but i want to know how can i get like console.log(is_address_exist(address)).

Comment: Oh, in that case replace this line  "xmlhttp.open('GET',url,true);" with "xmlhttp.open('GET',url,false);" to ensure the request doesn't run async